# Vector of non-const objects seems to be treated as constant in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a `std::vector` of objects being filled by de-referencing `std::unique_ptr`'s in the `push_back` calls. However, when I run through a mutable range-based for-loop, my modification to these objects stays local to the loop. In other words, it seems as those objects are being treated as constant, despite that lack of a `const` keyword in the loop. Here is minimal code to demonstrate what I'm seeing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Item
{
    public:
        typedef std::unique_ptr<Item> unique_ptr;

        inline static Item::unique_ptr createItem()
        {
            return std::unique_ptr<Item>(new Item());
        }

        inline const int getValue() const { return _value; }
        inline void setValue(const int val) { _value = val; }

    private:
        int _value;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Item> _my_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Item::unique_ptr item = Item::createItem();
        _my_vec.push_back(*item);
    }

    for (auto item : _my_vec)
    {
        // modify item (default value was 0)
        item.setValue(10);

        // Correctly prints 10
        std::cout << item.getValue() << std::endl;
    }


    for (auto item : _my_vec)
    {
        // Incorrectly prints 0's (default value)
        std::cout << item.getValue() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I suspect this has something to do with the move semantics of `std::unique_ptr`? But that wouldn't quite make sense because even if `push_back` is calling the copy constructor or something and copying the added item rather than pointing to it, the iterator is still passing over the same copies, no?

Interestingly enough, in my actual code, the class represented here by `Item` has a member variable that is a `vector` of shared pointers to objects of another class, and modifications to the objects being pointed to by those shared pointers persist between loops. This is why I suspect there's something funky with the `unique_ptr`.

Can anyone explain this behavior and explain how I may fix this issue while still using pointers?

Comment: use `for (auto& item : _my_vec)`. without `&` it access by value

Comment: @pergy: Oh man.... duh. You're right. I've spent so much time iterating over my shared pointer containers, I forgot how to properly iterate over actual objects. Thank you. Just goes to show how it's usually the obvious. Horses, not zebras, and all that....

Comment: nicely put question though :)

Comment: @marcman If something you try to modify was treated as a constant, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @LogicStuff: That's why I was so confused. Of course it was much simpler than that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a range-based for loop like that:

```
std::vector<int> v = ...;
for(auto elt : v) {
   ...
}
```

the elements of `v` are copied into `elt`.

In your example, in each iteration, you modify the local copy of the `Item` and not the `Item` in the vector.

To fix your issue, use a reference:

```
for (auto& item : _my_vec)
{
    item.setValue(10);
    std::cout << item.getValue() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Vector of non-const objects seems to be treated as constant

If it was *treated as constant*, then the compiler would scream at you, because writing to a constant is treated as ill-formed and the compiler would be required to scream at you. The shown code compiles just fine, with no warnings.

I suspect that you may be referring to the fact that you don't modify the elements within the vector. That is because you modify `auto item`. That item is not an element of the vector, it is a copy of the item in the vector. You could *refer* to the item within that vector by using a reference: `auto& item`. Then modifications to `item` would be modifications to the referred element of the vector.